# How to access the variable in iframe which contain another html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using iframe `test` in my `test.html`. Another `test2.html` file is loaded in that iframe `test`, i need to access the variable's which is used in the `test2.html`. Is there any way to access that in the `test.html`.

Here is my Samples

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           //this code is doesn't work
           var data1= document.getElementById('test').contentWindow.document.data;
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body,html{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            overflow:auto;
        }
        #test{
            height:250px;
            width:250px;
            border:1px solid gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="test" src="test2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**test2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = 'This data is retrived from test2.html';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#div')[0].textContent = data;
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body,html{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            overflow:auto;
        }
        #div{
            height:50px;
            width:200px;
            border:1px solid gray;
            margin:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div">Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions should be appreciated...!

Comment: did you try using contentWindow.data instead of contentWindow.document.data ?

Comment: That should be it. And also, you might have to check if the iframe is done loading. Because that might be the case of not getting the variable.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you should get the variable from `contentWindow` instead of `contentWindow.document`. And also, you might need to wait for the iframe to load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#test').on('load',function(){           
          var data1 = $('#test').get(0).contentWindow.data;
          // Or plain JavaScript
          // var data1 = document.getElementById('test').contentWindow.data;
     });
});
```